# Deployment Rule Sets and Java 7u51

Tags: java

I am trying to create a deployment rule set as described here: link

I created a simple rule, to allow everything from localhost like

```
<rule>
    <id location="http://localhost" />
    <action permission="run" />
</rule>
```

After I self-signed the jar file and deployed it in Windows when I try to run a self-signed app(jnlp) from localhost it is still blocked.

**Application Blocked by Deployment Rule Set.** 
**Can not verify self-signed Deployment Rule Set jar**

Q: Can anyone tell me why is not working? Do I have to sign the deployment jar with a verified certificate? I tried to use the deployment rules to avoid the block for my application. I don't want to lower the security or add my site to the trusted list.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the rule set jar has to be signed with a verified cert:

> The rule set defined in the ruleset.xml file must be packaged in a signed JAR file named DeploymentRuleSet.jar. The JAR file must be signed with a valid certificate from a trusted certificate authority.

(from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_rules.html#package)

This article seems to offer an alternative, which involves importing the self-signed cert on all target machines:

https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/self_signed_certificates_for_a

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I just have been throught this process and I was successfull. I followed [this blog post](http://wraithhacker.com/java-deployment-rule-set/) to make my own ruleset and it worked like a charm. But with only one trick the command to sign the jar the NA must be replaced by the certificate password or you must omit the storepass parameter so it will ask the password interactively.

I think you should check:

- You imported your cert as a signing CA so the jar signature can be verified (see the blog post).
- Your ruleset follows [the specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/deployment_rules.html) strictly. I had to remove some comments I added to the ruleset as it failed.
- Remove the http:// from the location